Display of author information in R package help file
I am creating my own package in R. For every function I define there, I have a roxygen2 file that with the following fields:
#' @title
#' @description
#' @param
#' @examples
#' @return
#' @export
#' @author

In all function files, the @author field looks like this:
#' @author [MyName](MyWebsite), [ORCID id: 0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX](https://orcid.org/0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX)
`

However, the help files for functions do not display the author field in the same way. Most help files look like this:
MyName, ORCID id: 0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX

where

"MyName" is a hyperlink to my website
"ORCID id: 0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX" is a hyperlink to my ORCID ID page

HOWEVER, in a very very small number of help files the @author field (in RStudio) looks like this:
MyName (www: https://www.XXX.XXX, ORCID id: 0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX)
I've consulted AIs but no progress:

the @author fields are indeed exactly the same
my DESCRIPTION field has Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE) in it, which explains why it works in nearly all functions
the Rd files of both the functions where it works and where it doesn't have the same author section:

\author{
\href{MyURL}{MyName}, \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX}{ORCID id: 0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX}
}

but are still displayed differently.
I am wondering whether it's something in the roxygen file before the @author field, but no matter how much I look at it, I can't see anything. Any ideas on what I might be missing?
Here's one function that works in the help file:
#' @title Retrieve statistics for general linear hypothesis tests (glht)
#'
#' @description This function computes an estimate, a confidence interval, and a p-value for a general linear hypothesis test.
#'
#' @param multcomp.object An object created with `multcomp::glht(model, a.1.row.model.matrix)
#' @param level A numeric vector specifying the confidence level for the confidence interval (default=0.95)
#'
#' @examples
#' set.seed(1)
#' predictor <- factor(c(sample(letters[1:4], 200, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)), sample(letters[1:4], 200, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))))
#' response <- c(runif(200, 0, 0.8), runif(200, 0.2, 1))
#' m <- lm(response ~ predictor)
#' multcomp.object <- multcomp::glht(m, matrix(c(0, 0, 1, -1), nrow=1))
#' glht.retriever(multcomp.object)
#' multcomp.object <- multcomp::glht(m, matrix(c(0, 0, 1, -1), nrow=1), alternative="less")
#' glht.retriever(multcomp.object)
#' multcomp.object <- multcomp::glht(m, matrix(c(0, 0, 1, -1), nrow=1), rhs=-0.08)
#' glht.retriever(multcomp.object)
#'
#' @return A numeric vector with the estimate defined by the model matrix for the model in question, its lower and upper 95% confidence interval, and a p-value for whether it significantly differs from 0
#'
#' @export
#'
#' @author [MyName](MyURL), [ORCID id: 0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX](https://orcid.org/0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX)

glht.retriever <- function(multcomp.object, level=0.95) {
   return(
      setNames(
         c(multcomp.object %>% confint(level=level) %>% "$"(confint),
           multcomp.object %>% summary %>% "$"(test) %>% "$"(pvalues) %>% as.numeric),
         c("estimate", "lwr", "upr", "p")))
}

This one doesn't:
#' @title Goodman & Kruskal's gamma
#'
#' @description This function computes Goodman & Kruskal's gamma.
#'
#' @param a.rbyc.table A table/matrix of frequencies with r rows and c columns
#' @param CI.level The desired confidence interval
#'
#' @examples
#' addmargins(a.rbyc.table <- matrix(c(70,10,10,15,60,15,10,20,35,5,10,40), ncol=4))
#' GoodmanKruskal.gamma(a.rbyc.table)
#'
#' @return A 5-element list with Goodman & Kruskal's gamma, its standard error, its z-score and p-value, and its lower and upper confidence interval boundaries
#'
#' @references Sheskin, David J. 2011. Handbook of parametric and non-parametric statistical procedures. 5th ed. Boca Raton, FL: Taylor & Francis (Test 32)
#'
#' @export
#'
#' @author [MyName](MyURL), [ORCID id: 0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX](https://orcid.org/0000-0002-XXXX-XXXX)

GoodmanKruskal.gamma <- function (
      a.rbyc.table,
      CI.level=0.95) {
   nc <- 0; for (i in 1:(nrow(a.rbyc.table)-1)) {
      for (j in 1:(ncol(a.rbyc.table)-1)) {
         nc <- nc + "*"(
            a.rbyc.table[i,j],
            sum(a.rbyc.table[
               (i+1):nrow(a.rbyc.table),
               (j+1):ncol(a.rbyc.table)]))
      }}
   nd <- 0; for (i in 1:(nrow(a.rbyc.table)-1)) {
      for (j in ncol(a.rbyc.table):2) {
         nd <- nd + "*"(
            a.rbyc.table[i,j],
            sum(a.rbyc.table[
               (i+1):nrow(a.rbyc.table),
               1:(j-1)]))
      }}
   gamma <- (nc-nd) / (nc+nd)
   se <- sqrt("/"(
      nc+nd,
      sum(a.rbyc.table) * (1-gamma^2)))^-1
   z <- gamma * sqrt((nc+nd)/(sum(a.rbyc.table)*(1-gamma^2)))
   list("Goodman & Kruskal's gamma"=gamma,
        "std. error"=se,
        "inferential stats"=c("z"=z, "p (2-tailed)"=2*(1-pnorm(abs(z)))),
        "confidence interval"=c(
           "lower"=gamma - qnorm(1-((1-CI.level)/2), lower.tail=TRUE) * se,
           "upper"=gamma + qnorm(1-((1-CI.level)/2), lower.tail=TRUE) * se))
}



I cannot reproduce. It works as expected for both functions if I create a test package. Do you have a github link to your actual code? What do you see in the .Rd files? Are R, RStudio and roxygen2 updated?

MyName and MyURL are identical in both? Or do they sometimes contain non-ASCII characters?

Thanks for looking into this. I got it fixed literally 5 minutes ago after re-compiling and installing this 15 times w/ different versions of the roxygen2 files but I don't know what fixed it:

the Rd files had the same author field for the two functions even though they displayed it differently;
NyName / MyURL were identical, I had pasted the @author field into all function files (saved as UTF-8), there were no non-ASCII characters;
R and RStudio were recent versions: 4.4.1 and a 2024 version of RStudio and I didn't update them before it started working.

